# Azure SWA CLI deploy ignoring resource group

Tags: swa-cli

I'm using the Azure Static Web Apps CLI (SWA CLI) to deploy, but it appears to be ignoring the --resource-group command.

I have 2 separate resource groups within the same Azure subscription (same tenant), with each resource group containing a Static Web App that has the same name.

Issuing the following command:

**swa deploy ./spa --env production --tenant-id ABC --subscription-id DEF --resource-group GHI --app-name JKL**

Results in the app being deployed to the Static Web App created first (in let's say resource group XYZ), essentially ignoring the resource group command-line option.

Even though the two Static Web Apps have the same name, I was expecting the --resource-group command line option to deploy to the app in the specified resource group.

UPDATE: Upgraded SWA CLI to version 1.1.3 but problem remains as above

Answer (score 0):

I tried using deployment token and it worked fine.

```
swa deploy ./spa --deployment-token $(az staticwebapp secrets list --name <application-name> --resource-group <resource-group> --query "properties.apiKey" | tr -d '"')
```